# Delete complex conjugate in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with complex numbers. I would like to delete a number $z$ that is in my list if **at least one** of these conditions is met:

- $-z$ is also in the list
- $\bar{z}$ is in the list
- $-\bar{z}$ is in the list

Where $\bar{z}$ represents the complex conjugate of $z$.

For example in the list:
$$L=\{4,2+\mathrm{i},-4,3,-2+\mathrm{i},-2-\mathrm{i},2-\mathrm{i}\}$$
After applying the algorithm only the element $3$ remains:
$$L\to\tilde{L}=\{3\}$$

The problem is that I can have up to 6000 elements in my list. Is there a smart way to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or use Gather

```
Gather[
{4, 2 + I, -4, 3, -2 + I, -2 - I, 2 - I}, #1 == Conjugate[#2] || #1 + #2 == 
     0 || #1 + Conjugate[#2] == 0 & ] // Cases[{x_} :> x]
```

```
{3}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy):

```
Cases[
    GroupBy[{4, 2+I, -4, 3, -2+I, -2-I, 2-I}, Abs @* ReIm],
    {v_} :> v
]
```

> {3}

Comment: I'd suggest `Abs@Re@# + I*Abs@Im@# &` instead of `Norm`.  (Consider `{..., -4 + 3 I, 3 + 4 I,...}`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 good point